# draw with the mouse on QQuickPaintedItem

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have this code

```
class cCanvas : public QQuickPaintedItem
..
..
void cCanvas::paint(QPainter *ppainter)
{
    ppainter->setPen(QPen(colorValue()));
    ppainter->drawLine(0, 0, rand() % 255 ,100);
}
```

QML

```
MultiPointTouchArea {
    onPressed {
        canvas.update();
    }
}
```

It works, but when drawing each new line, the canvas is cleared, previous line is deleted. But I want the lines to stay.

QML Canvas have requestPaint();

How to call this method for QQuickPaintedItem?

**How to correctly create the ability to draw with the mouse on QQuickPaintedItem?**

(Drawing on the QML canvas itself is not suitable because of the speed of work, since drawing occurs using calculations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt does not keep a cache of what was painted, so you only see what was painted last. A possible solution is to save the line instructions in a QPainterPath:

```cpp
#ifndef CCANVAS_H
#define CCANVAS_H

#include <QPainterPath>
#include <QQuickPaintedItem>

class CCanvas : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor NOTIFY colorChanged)
    QML_ELEMENT
public:
    CCanvas(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void requestPaint();
    void paint(QPainter *painter);
    const QColor &color() const;
    void setColor(const QColor &newColor);

signals:
    void colorChanged();

private:
    QPainterPath m_path;
    QColor m_color;
};

#endif // CCANVAS_H
```

```cpp
#include "ccanvas.h"

#include <QPainter>

CCanvas::CCanvas(QQuickItem *parent):QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{

}

void CCanvas::requestPaint()
{
    QPointF start(0, 0);
    QPointF end(rand() % 255, 100);
    m_path.moveTo(start);
    m_path.lineTo(end);
    update();
}

void CCanvas::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    painter->setPen(QPen(m_color));
    painter->drawPath(m_path);
}

const QColor &CCanvas::color() const
{
    return m_color;
}

void CCanvas::setColor(const QColor &newColor)
{
    if (m_color == newColor)
        return;
    m_color = newColor;
    emit colorChanged();
    update();
}
```

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import Canvas 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    CCanvas{
        id: canvas
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "red"
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 500; running: true; repeat: true
        onTriggered: canvas.requestPaint()
    }
}
```

```cpp
QT += quick

CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += \
        ccanvas.cpp \
        main.cpp

HEADERS += \
        ccanvas.h

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

CONFIG += qmltypes
QML_IMPORT_NAME = Canvas
QML_IMPORT_MAJOR_VERSION = 1
```

A similar solution can be done with a QImage.